# Binarize pixels by value

Tags: python, opencv

I want to binarize a gray image by value, so pixels that are between a and b will be 0, and 255 otherwise. I tried `cv2.threshold` but this didn't produce the right effect. So I tried:

```
def cut(img,d,u):
    for x,line in enumerate(img):
        for y,px in enumerate(line):
            if px < d or px > u:
                img[x][y]=0
            else:
                img[x][y]=255
```

But this way is low performance, what is the right way to do that, use histogram equalization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [inRange](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cv2.inRange) function.

You can do something like:

```
binary = cv2.inRange(gray_image, d, u)
```

You then probably need to invert the binary image:

```
binary_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(binary)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure your image is in an allowed data format for `opencv` Then you should use the `threshold` function or `inRange` function to create the binary image/matrix according to your needs. With the `threshold` function, you'd need to apply it twice, since you have a range, but that's not too complicated. There's a really nice blog post on this [here](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2013/05/thresholding.html).

Comment: _Isn't too complicated_ isn't very useful. Consider posting a code snippet with your solution